# drupal jquery mobile datepicker cannot select year

Tags: 7

I'm using drupal 7 with jquery.mobile-1.4.5.

I had created a form with date field, using Inline Datepicker

```
  $form['body']['dob'] = array( 
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Date of Birth',     
    '#attributes' => array('data-role'=>'date', 'id'=>'dob'),
  );
```

The Inline Datepicker is showing exactly like the demo in http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/

However, I would like to have a inline datepicker, with a dropdown menu for user to select year in calendar.
Eg: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

I had tried adding in below function but it doesn't work.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });
```

Is there any way I can allow user select year in the inline datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module which has several options regarding to your requirement. You can use date functionalities in your custom form.

For example,

```
$form['body']['dob'] = array( 
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => 'Date of Birth', 
);
```

will have options to select date, month and year.

If `#type => 'date_popup'`, it  will popup with calendar which allows user to select date.

Check this link for more info [date example](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/add-date-field-drupal-7-custom-form#gsc.tab=0)